# Negative test score for random forest

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, random-forest

Hi I am using a random forest classifier to product logerror. The log error contains both =ve & -ve values. After running the classifier with different settings. i am able to get training test score of around 0.8  but the test score is always negative. why is that so? 
should i be using abs(log error) for prediction or is my choice for random forest wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Choice of the random forest might be wrong but you better check it in context of data as if you have shared data here it would be easy to help you at the exact point. But, I suggest you try Knn if your total observations are around 1000-2000.

Also, if you are using any kind of encoding to convert categorical data to nominal please use only one hot encoding as other my add values to attributes.

You should have checked correlation of attributes to the target variable as the low correlation of target variable in test data may result in the negative score.

Apart from above all, distribution of data plays a vital role in randomforest regresssion. So, try to check distribution and apply methods such as box-cox to convert data in normal distribution.